# Recursive formula for Multivariate Normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

i have a multivariate normal distribution with pdf as is shown here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution
i want to find the cdf, but there is no close type. I'm trying to find a recursive formula for the multivariate normal distribution to use instead but still, no close type found. Can someone help me? I want to use it to find the inverse $F(x)$.

Comment: Do you know such things for the univariate normal distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by recursive formula for a continuous distribution function?

Comment: @Bob1123  i'm not sure if these is even possible. sorry, if i'm wrong. If you know a way to find a close type for the cdf, please let me know.

Comment: @MANMAID my response to Bob is also for you.Sorry if i confused you

Comment: $$\begin{align} & F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \Pr(X_1\le x_1\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_k\le x_k) \\[10pt] = {} & \int_{-\infty}^{x_k} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{x_{k-1}} \left( \vphantom{\int} \cdots \left( \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \,du_1  \right) \cdots \right) \, du_{k-1}    \right) \, du_k \end{align}$$ where (lower-case) $f$ is the density function. $\qquad$

Comment: @EmilyPeterson First, the word recursion make sense if r.v takes discrete value. Second, for normal distribution, the integral is not easily computable, you may approx. it.